# Sorting List of Control by name

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to sort list of Controls by their name. This is my code to loop through Form Controls and add them to list.

```
 Public Sub FindControls(ByVal owner As Control, ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal name As String)
    'list.Clear()
    For Each c As Control In owner.Controls
        If c.Name.Contains(name) And c.Name.Length < 4 Then
            list.Add(c)
        End If
        If c.HasChildren Then FindControls(c, list, name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then i want to loop through this list and get value from these controls by index.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To ElektrikList.Count - 1
        If ElektrikList(i).Name = "T" & i.ToString Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next
```

I named all my controls "T00" (example: "T1" or "T50"), but they are added to the list with wrong order, so for example index 4 in this List is T23, not T4 as I would wish.

Is there any way to sort it? I tried everything i found but I can't get it to work.

At first i tried to create all these controls dynamically, but I want to add them on different Panels with categories and so on, so i thought it would be really painful to make this.

Comment: Why did you tag this with C#?

Comment: Use a Dictionary(Of String, Control) instead.

Comment: [List.Sort(IComparer<T>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I named all my controls "T00" (example: "T1" or "T50"), but they are
> added to the list with wrong order

If you're only interested in those specific controls, then search for them in that order using the recurse option of [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=net-5.0) and add them to your list:

```
Public Function FindControls() As List(Of Control)
    Dim ctrls As New List(Of Control)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        Dim ctrlName As String = "T" & i.ToString("00")
        Dim ctrl As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ctrlName, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(ctrl) Then
            ctrls.Add(ctrl)
        End If
    Next
    Return ctrls
End Function
```

Comment: Works exactly how i wanted, just changed the format to "0", because of how I named my controls.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
Dim sorted = From ctrl In owner.Controls
                Order By ctrl.Name

For Each c As Control In sorted
(...)
```

I followed the example from [Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq).